# jBPM 6 API usage to call REST API

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I looked through the jBPM6 user guide, and I found that there are URL's available for each operation, like: `http://serverurl:8080/business-central/rest/task/query?potentialOwner=bpmuser`
This URL is used to get the tasks assigned to `bpmuser`. I'm able to request this URL using Google's REST client without any errors. The problem is though, that I'm getting an authorization error when I try to request this URL from my Java program. Could anybody help me with the problem I'm having?

Answer (score 2):

You can send authentication details in header as below.

```
String authData = "krisv" + ":" + "krisv";
String encoded = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(authData.getBytes());
get.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

See my answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656151/jbpm-console-remote-authetication-through-java/28667254#28667254) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation?

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html

Are you sending the user / password?

Look at this section -> 17.1.1. The REST Remote Java RuntimeEngine Factory